# Code to merge data in multiple documents by column

Tags: vba, excel, merge

Is there a way to merge the data in multiple excel spreadsheets together by column?

I have 200 spreadsheets, each with text in the first 100 columns (A-CV).
I would like to merge all the "A" columns from these 200 documents together, all the "B" columns together, all the "C" columns together, and so on.

As for the merging, no particular order is required. As long as the cells themselves don't get merged.

Due to the large amount of text the code would be merging, it would be more practical to be able to merge one column at a time across all spreadsheets into a unique file, then repeat that with all other columns (A-CV), instead of attempting to merge all the columns (from all spreadsheets) together into one single file.

I found a code that merges columns, but it's not quite what I need. Is there a way to modify this code to help with what I described above?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

    Dim cell As Range
    For i = 1 To 50
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Cat 2" Then
        Columns(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Cat 6" Then
        Columns(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Cat 4" Then
        Columns(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("C1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you need more information, please let me know. And if I need to rename the documents a certain way to help with the process, I'm definitely willing to do that.

The merged data can be sent to a spreadsheet, word document, or notepad. I'm fine with any of these options.

UPDATE:  This is the new code with modifications. The issues I am having are in the comment below.

```
 Sub copydocument()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 On Error GoTo resetsettings
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 MyPath = "C:\Users\HNR\Desktop\A\" 'Path of folder with \ at the end
 MyExtension = "*.xlsx"
 Myfile = Dir(MyPath & MyExtension)
 While Myfile <> vbNullString
 Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & Myfile)
 lr = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lr1).Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & (lr + 1))
 wb1.Close
Myfile = Dir
Wend
resetsettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: how many rows are there in each spreadsheet? Do you want to paste the same columns side by side or one below another in the new worksheet?

Comment: Answer to Question 1:  Each spreadsheet has a different number of rows. I opened several and the highest row count was 2500; however, there may be some spreadsheets with more. Is there a way to merge the columns and then do a "sort/filter" to bring the cells with text to the top and those without to the bottom? Or a way to only target cells with text and ignore those that are empty when merging? [Answer to Question 2 is below]

Comment: Answer to Question 2: I wanted to paste the columns one below another in a new worksheet. And have one worksheet for all column A's, another separate worksheet for all column B's, and so on, so that I don't have one large document for all columns together, as that might cause my computer to crash.

Comment: Having  a lot of worksheets with large amounts of data on a workbook might crash your computer none the less

Comment: Yes, that is true. Perhaps merging 200 documents at once, even by a single column, isn't the best idea. It may be better to do half of that (or a fraction of it) and try to lessen the impact.

Comment: It's just opening 200 documents one by one and copying the columns...You cant copy from all 200 documents at once..The macro might require some time to go through all the documents but it's not a big load with 2000 rows per document.

Comment: If you think merging 25 documents at once is better than 200 at once - or any other number of documents - I will be more than happy to take your advice and try it out that way. I don't mind breaking it down. :)

Comment: you cant merge multiple documents at once you can do it one by one 200 times for 200 documents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141955/discussion-between-irisrose-and-sivaprasath-v).

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to do what you want, I would recommend looking into Power Query. It gives you a great GUI to work with to accomplish this. Depending on your version of excel it is either a free add-on or part of the shipped product(for new versions of office).

You do not need to know how to code to use this, you just need to understand the concepts.

While its not exactly the answer you are after i have successfully taught several people at my work place how to use this application that would have previously been reliant on me or someone else with VBA skills.

Comment: Yes, I checked and Power Query is included with my excel. I only learned about coding 4 days ago, so I definitely don't know "code" but I would be very grateful for any help you could offer. And with your patience, I would be happy to follow along with any instructions you give. :)

Comment: While iterating over a folder for each file is a little harder than what I have previously taught people in powerQuery, there is an example of how to do this in the following link:
http://excelunplugged.com/2016/05/28/use-power-querys-get-data-from-folder-to-get-data-from-multiple-excel-files/

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub copydocument()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo resetsettings
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
MyPath = "c:\Users\foo\" 'Path of folder with \ at the end
MyExtension = "*.xlsx"
Myfile = Dir(MyPath & MyExtension)
While Myfile <> vbNullString
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & Myfile)
lr = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:CV" & lr1).Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & (lr + 1))
wb1.close
Myfile = Dir
Wend
resetsettings:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This macro will go through all the files in the folder and copy the sheet1 range and paste it in the active workbook sheet1. if you have headers and dont want them to repeat you can copy the header to the sheet1 of activeworkbook then copy range from (A2:CV &lr1).

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you for the code. I am trying it out right now and having mixed results. I have placed your code in my original message so you can see how I am applying it. Right now, I had the code working for a minute where it was copying multiple A columns from all the spreadsheets my designated folder, Folder A, but now it's not even copying the entirety of one column. Could you give me guidance on what I can do to improve the results? What I did was change the column range from "A1:A" to just "A".

Comment: You are just copying the last cell in column A for all documents as per your edits. If you wanted to copy only Entire column. I suggest you change it from A& lr1 to A1:Alr1 to copy the range. Rest of the edit is fine.

Comment: With this new change, the code is neatly merging the documents, but it's merging them by row and not by column. This is how I modified the code. Could you tell me if it's correct?  wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Alr1").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & (lr + 1)). This code merged all the Row 1's from each document, not all the column A's from each document.

Comment: The  edit must be like wb1.sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lr1).copy

Comment: This finally did the trick. Thank you so much! I feel embarrassed about needing help every step of the way. I get lost too easily and I'm sorry for taking up so much of your time. I am grateful you were patient enough to help me out. Your kindness has made my work a lot easier. Thank you again.